# How to parse a json fetched from Volley Android

Tags: android

Heres my code of Volley Fetching API Request How do i parse?
i wanted somethinf like : $response[0]

```
val sq = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
        Response.Listener<String> { response ->
            //print the response
            Log.i("GoogleIO","Response is : $response")
        }, Response.ErrorListener {
            //Log the error
            Log.i("GoogleIO","That din't work")
        })

    //Add the request to the RequestQueue
    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(sq)
```

Comment: Why don't you use Retrofit instead of Volley?

Comment: You can use some libraries like gson or moshi, you can google those libraries. As above, you can try retrofit also. For kotlin support moshi is better, with codegen

Comment: Retrofit is standard for android development and is recommended to be used with moshi, not all google libraries are better :) advice: go and check job offers, you will see some libraries and tech stack that is used by for example senior developers

Answer (score 0):

Lets suppose you have this json string in response

```
{
name: "John",
age: 31,
city: "New York"
}
```

you can parse this string like this

```
        try {
        JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(response);
        String name=obj.getString("name");
        int age=obj.getInt("age");
        String city=obj.getString("city");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gson for that:

First put the dependency in your app level `build.gradle` file.

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
```

Then you can add this:

```
var gson = new Gson()
var st = gson.toJson(response)
Log.i("GoogleIO","Response is : $st")
```